# Is it Necessary to create a custom array adapter class for Objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I had this error where it would say it cannot resolve constructor Array Adapter. Thinking about making one but wanted to make sure if it was necessary. I did override the toString method in the item class as well.

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(   LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MyApplication MyArraylist;


    ArrayAdapter <MyItem> arrayAdapter;

    MyItem item1 = new MyItem();
    item1.setName("MyFirstHomework");
    item1.setGrade(60);
    item1.setCategory("Homework");

    MyArraylist = new MyApplication();
    MyArraylist.getItemsArrayList().add(item1);





    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>
    (this,R.layout.Myview,MyArraylist);  //THIS IS WHERE THE CONSTRUCTOR       
    ERROR IS


    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyXML); 
    v.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);




    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment,container, false);
}
}
```

Also on ListView findViewById says it cannot resolve method. Been trying for hours now. Any Suggestions?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ArrayList<MyItem> MyArrayList;


    public ArrayList<MyItem> getMyArrayList() {

            MyArrayList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
            return MyArrayList;
    }



    }
```

Comment: `MyArraylist` is object of `MyApplication`, Is `MyApplication` is ArrayList of Item?

Comment: You'll need to show us MyApplication.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do something like `MyApplication<MyItem> MyArraylist = new MyApplication<MyItem>()` to pass the correct type to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor? (that's assuming `MyApplication` is an `ArrayList`).

Comment: MyApplication does contain an ArrayList and thats it and thats why im calling the MyApplication class because it contains the arrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things happening here that will block your progress.

Each time you call `getItemsArrayList()` to add a new item, a new `ArrayList` is created which is going to wipe out the previous items you have added.  This can be fixed by creating the ArrayList in the constructor of `MyApplication` rather than in the method.

Also, you are passing the `MyApplication` object rather than the `ArrayList<MyItem>` object to the `ArrayAdapter` constructor.  This can be resolved by adding a new variable, `myList` that references the `ArrayList` in `MyApplication`.

Here's some code with comments to show what I mean:

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(   LayoutInflater inflater,
                               ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MyApplication app; // renamed from MyArraylist
    ArrayAdapter <MyItem> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<MyItem> myList; // this is a new variable to reference the list

    // create application and get the items list
    app = new MyApplication();
    myList = app.getItemsArrayList();

    // create items and add to list
    MyItem item1 = new MyItem();
    item1.setName("Title");
    item1.setGrade(60);
    item1.setCategory("Type");
    myList.add(item1);

    // use myList instead of app (renamed from MyArraylist) in the constructor
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this, R.layout.Myview, myList); 

    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyXML); 
    v.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment,container, false);
  }
}
```

And:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  private ArrayList<MyItem> myArrayList;

  public MyApplication() {
    // create the list in the constructor
    myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
  }

  public ArrayList<MyItem> getMyArrayList() {
    // return the already initialized list rather than creating a new one
    return myArrayList;
  }
}
```

Lastly, `findViewById()` method will only work if your `Fragment` class subclasses [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)) or some other class that has a `findViewById()` method.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. You answered both of my questions. Just wondering if i did something like this 

ListView v = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MyXML); 

Would that work? I tried doing that but that app crashes. I get this error 

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Looking at an example in the [Fragment docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), it appears what you suggest would likely be the way to go.  If you still have problems, you'd be best to post it as a new question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code is trying to pass a MyAppliction object to the ListAdapter constructor.  This won't compile because MyArraylist is of type MyApplication:

```
MyArraylist = new MyApplication();
MyArraylist.getItemsArrayList().add(item1);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this,R.layout.Myview,MyArraylist);
```

Instead, did you mean to pass the actual ArrayList object from inside MyApplication to the constructor like this?

```
MyApplication myapp = new MyApplication();
ArrayList<MyItem> list = myapp.getItemsArrayList();
list.add(item1);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this, R.layout.Myview, list);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is also good but br3nt answered both of my questions so I'm accepting his answer.